# netty 4 client conection through proxy server

Tags: java, proxy, netty

Is there any way to write client with netty to connect to the server, through proxy server? I searched in documentation and in exmples, but there is no information, about working through proxy. Is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

We have not build in support for http proxy etc. You will need to handle it by your own.